# Weighted Q-binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, analytic-number-theory, hypergeometric-function, q-series

A possible identity popped up in a project for college, and it features q-binomial coefficient, which can be interpreted as the generating function for the number of Ferrer's boards fitting into a $k\times N-k$ box. One representation of the q-binomial is

$$\frac{(q)_N}{(q)_k (q)_{N-k}}$$

where

$$(a)_n = (1-a)(1-aq)\cdots (1-aq^{n-1})$$

Something else that pops up is

$$\frac{(aq)_N}{(aq)_k (aq)_{N-k}}$$

which looks like the q-binomial, but I can't seem to interpret it as a generating series, nor can I find reference to anything similar in literature. Any suggestions for what it might be?

Comment: $(a)_n$ is a function of $a$ and $q$? Then what is $(q)_n$? Confusing

Comment: More properly, we define $(a;q)_n= (1-a)(1-aq)\cdots (1-aq^{n-1})$, but it is common to write $(a)_n$ for $(a;q)_n$. So $(q)_n = (1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots (1-q^n)$.